# Do bash scripts timeout?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Do long running bash scritps close themselves after a while? That is do they timeout?
I have tried searching this seemingly simple question but can't seem to find the answer.

I am running a bash script over night in order to gather data but my script stops running by morning.

My scripts looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
port="3000"
host="192.168.1.1"
(
for(( y=0; y<225; y++))
do
    for(( x=0; x<79; x++ ))
    do
    sleep 3
    echo "command1"
    sleep 35
    done
echo "command2"
sleep 300
done
) | telnet "${host}" "${port}" | tee -a -i outputFile
```

I'm not sure if the problem could be related to my output file either. Currently my output file has over 100 000 lines.

Any advice or direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: `bash` is the wrong tool. You should use `expect`.

Comment: The script will finish after about eight and a half day. `(((35+3)×79)+300)×225=742,950` seconds and the for-loops are done.

Comment: I would be using expect but I do not have administrative powers on the machine I am using so I was unable to install it. I am reduced to using bash. Woe is me. I am quite happy with the bash script though. It does it's job if only it would run over night. Do you know if bash timesout after a certain amount of time?

Comment: bash does not time out, what could time out is the telnet connection ( if so configured, but I am no telnet expert to know for sure ). IMHO if you do need to have something running overnight, start a screen or tmux session or the remote machine. Tmux and screen have learning curve for attaching and detaching sessions but they work wonders once you are used to them.

Comment: Mook: My problem is that the script doesn't run for 8 days. I would love it if it did. But it won't. Do you know if bash times out?

Comment: Perhaps it's using too much CPU?   Check what ``ulimit -t`` reports.

Comment: Thanks Sergiy, I didn't look up telnet timeout. I really should have done that. My project is coming to a close but it would just be nice to know the reason for my bash script constantly closing. I'll have a look at Tmux and screen in my spare time. Thanks for that. If you leave you comment as a questions I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @RayButterworth. I'll look into that latter. I'll have to ask my boss for permission to run the script overnight again as the data has already been collected. Hopefully in a week  or so I'll be able to test it again.

Comment: I have become skeptical that it is the telnet that is timing out because when I telnet into it and run a command it lasted over the weekend but when I us my bash script it times out.